# Easily Determine if Field Is Required

Tags: entities

I have a large set of Content Types,each with a fair amount of fields.  IS there a way to programatically report on whether those fields are required or not?  It is tedious to click on each field to check it.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [Field Info API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/group/field_info/7) functions to get this information.

Since the 'required' setting is on the instance level, not the field level, you'll need to use either [`field_info_instances()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7), which will get the instance information for all fields attached to a given entity type and bundle:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$bundle = 'article';

$info = field_info_instances($entity_type, $bundle);
foreach ($info as $field_instance) {
  $required = (bool)$field_instance['required'];
}
```

or alternatively, if you only want the info for a single field, the [`field_info_instance`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7) function:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$bundle = 'article';
$field_name = 'field_my_field';

$info = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle);
$required = (bool)$info['required'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can use [field_info_fields()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_fields/7) function to get list of all defined fields and its settings (i.e required this field or not).

In Drupal 6 the similar functionality provided by [content_fields()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!cck!content.module/function/content_fields/6) function.